# Pyspark Sedona: Want to Spatial Join but got Error "Points of LinearRing do not form a closed line string"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, polygon, spatial, apache-sedona

So my two dataframes look like this

spatial_wi_df (contains POINTS)

```
root
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- wagonnumber: long (nullable = true)
|-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
|-- speed: double (nullable = true)
|-- geometry: geometry (nullable = false)
|-- wi_geometry_meter: geometry (nullable = true)
```

spatial_station_groups_gdf (contains POLYGONS)

```
root
|-- geo_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- polygon: geometry (nullable = false)
```

In the end I want to check if any points from spatial_wi_df are contained by polygons from spatial_station_groups_gdf:

```
spatial_wi_df.createOrReplaceTempView("points")
spatial_station_groups_gdf.createOrReplaceTempView("geofences")
spatial_join_result = spark_sedona.sql("SELECT g.geo_name, p.wagonnumber FROM points AS p, geofences AS g WHERE ST_Contains(g.polygon, p.geometry)")
```

But got Error Message:
[image]

I already tried 3 Approaches to fix the POLYGONS, but everytime the same Error Message:

#### Buffer Option

```
spatial_station_groups_gdf.createOrReplaceTempView("spatial_station_gdf_buffer")
spatial_station_groups_gdf = spark_sedona.sql("SELECT *, ST_Buffer(spatial_station_gdf_buffer.polygon, 0) AS polygon_buffered FROM spatial_station_gdf_buffer")
```

#### MakeValid

```
spatial_station_groups_gdf.createOrReplaceTempView("spatial_station_gdf_valid")
spatial_station_groups_gdf = spark_sedona.sql("SELECT *, spatial_station_gdf_valid.polygon FROM spatial_station_gdf_valid LATERAL VIEW ST_MakeValid(polygon, false) spatial_station_gdf_valid AS polygon_valid")
```

#### Draw ConvexHull

```
spatial_station_groups_gdf.createOrReplaceTempView("spatial_station_gdf_hull")
spatial_station_groups_gdf = spark_sedona.sql("SELECT *, ST_ConvexHull(spatial_station_gdf_hull.polygon) AS polygon_hull FROM spatial_station_gdf_hull")
```

Any Experience/Solution with broken polygons issue?